# C++ ABI issue related to STL

Tags: c++, stl, abi

I have searched the net without any conclusive answers to issue related to lack of C++ ABI when it comes to exporting c++ classes accross dll boundaries in windows.

I can use extern c and provide a c like api to a library , but I would like end users to be able to use classes that us stl containers.

What generic patterns do you use for exporting a class that uses stl container across dll boundaries , in a safe manner? e.g. best practice.

This question is for experienced library authors.

Regards
Niladri

Comment: C++ has no common ABI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no defined C++ ABI and it does differ between compilers in terms of memory layout, name mangling, RTL etc.

It gets worse than that though.  If you are targeting MSVC compiler for example, your dll/exe can be built with different macros that configure the STL to not include iterator checks so that it is faster.  This modifies the layout of STL classes and you end up breaking the One Definition Rule (ODR) when you link (but the link still succeeds).  If the ODR is violated then your program will crash seemingly randomly.

I would recommend maybe reading Imperfect C++ which has a chapter on the subject of C++ ABIs.

The upshot is that either:

- you compile the dll specifically for the target compiler that is going to link to it and name the dll's appropriately (like boost does it). In this case you can't avoid ODR violations so the user of the library must be able to recompile the library themselves with different options.
- Provide a portable C API and provide C++ wrapper classes for convenience that are compiled on the client side of the API.  This is time consuming but portable.

Comment: What STL are you referring to? If you mean "C++ Standard Library implementation supplied with MSVC", you should change your wording.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz ha yes maybe it should just be 'TL'

Comment: This is probably the most clear and concise answer to this question I have found on the net! Thanks

Comment: thought I would add a reference to ODR - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CppComponents https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents

You can export classes and interfaces across dll boundaries even across different compilers.

The library is header-only so nothing to build. To use it, you will need MSVC 2013 and/or GCC 4.8 as it uses C++11 variadic templates extensively.

See presentation from C++Now

https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2014/blob/master/files/cppnow2014_bandela_presentation.pdf?raw=true

https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents_cppnow_examples has the examples from the presentation.

Comment: looks very interesting and impressive , looks like a solution but I have to support vc 9. I will use your solution for my mordern libraries though!